# Combining SFMC Job, Send and Click Tracking Extracts to create Impression Tracking by Job Report

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio, data-views, tracking-extract

I am trying to create a custom report in SQL to mimic following 'Impression Tracking by Job Report' in SFMC for all Jobs but currently testing with just one job ID to narrow down my testing by I am unable to achieve the results to match SFMC's inbuilt report. I have my SQL query below which not working in few parts and Total and Unique numbers are not really same as in SFMC. Where am I doing wrong?

Once I get the Impression Region Numbers right, I need to pull Email Name and Campaign Name from different data views as well as these tracking extracts doesn't have those fields and would require joined with _JOB or_SENT data views I guess

[image]

```
SELECT
      s.SubscriberKey,
      s.SendID,
      c.URLID,
      c.URL,
      c.url_alias,
      s.ImpressionRegionName as impression_region_name,
      SUM(CA.ImpressionCount) as Total_ImpressionRegions_Sent,
      c.Total_Clicks_Per_Subscriber_PerJob_PerRegion_PerLink,
      c.Unique_Clicks_Per_Subscriber_PerJob_PerRegion_PerLink,
      c.Unique_Clicks_Per_Subscriber_PerJob_PerRegion_PerLink * 100.0 / SUM(CA.ImpressionCount) as Region_CTR
FROM
      send_impression_daily s
LEFT JOIN ( 
            SELECT
                  SubscriberKey,
                  SendID AS job_id,
                  BatchID,
                  ListID,
                  URLID,
                  URL,
                  Alias AS url_alias,
                  ImpressionRegionName,
                  SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY SubscriberKey)   AS Total_Clicks_Per_Subscriber_PerJob_PerRegion_PerLink,
                  COUNT(DISTINCT SubscriberKey)                     AS Unique_Clicks_Per_Subscriber_PerJob_PerRegion_PerLink
                FROM
                  click_impression_daily  
                WHERE SendID='11111' AND ImpressionRegionName='01__Rule_1__LAY_Dynamic_Content_-_14'    
                GROUP BY 
                    SubscriberKey,
                    SendID,
                    BatchID,
                    ListID,
                    URLID,
                    URL,
                    Alias,
                    ImpressionRegionName          ) c
    ON s.SubscriberKey = c.SubscriberKey
    AND s.SendID = c.job_id
    /*AND s.BatchID = c.BatchID*/
    AND s.ListID = c.ListID
CROSS APPLY (
    Select COUNT(SubscriberKey) AS ImpressionCount
    from send_impression_daily
    where SendID = s.SendID
    and ImpressionRegionName = s.ImpressionRegionName
) CA
WHERE s.SendID='11111' AND s.ImpressionRegionName='01__Rule_1__LAY_Dynamic_Content_-_14'
GROUP BY 
    s.SubscriberKey,
    s.SendID,
    c.URLID,
    c.URL,
    c.url_alias,
    s.ImpressionRegionName,
    c.Total_Clicks_Per_Subscriber_PerJob_PerRegion_PerLink,
    c.Unique_Clicks_Per_Subscriber_PerJob_PerRegion_PerLink
```